# How to compare two datagridview's

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need help with my litle project.

So what i need is to compere two datagridview's.

I have made something like this

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("test= '{0}'", textBox4.Text);

(dataGridView2.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("test= '{0}'", textBox4.Text);
```

and it works for manual search.

But i need to look "test" in dgw1 and "test" in dgw2 and look if values are same.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq for this as follows:

```
var idsNotInB = (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("id"))
        .Except(dataGridView2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("id")));
```

Comment: @user2768054 It is `(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).AsEnumerable()`... not `dataGridView2.AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: .Except(dataGridView2.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("id")));